# Get RGB image of Segmented Objects?

Tags: ros, tabletop-object-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
is there any way to get rgb image of segmented objects in tabletop_object_detector node?

(Actually i want to send the rgb image of segmented objects to a 2d object recognition node which is using sift library!)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35751/get-rgb-image-of-segmented-objects?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, just requires a few steps.

1. Choose which camera you want to use (on a PR2, narrow_stereo might be a good choice). I'll refer to this as `camera`.
2. Create a `[image_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_geometry).PinholeCameraModel` using `camera/camera_info`.
3. Let's say you have a PointStamped called `object_center` which represents the center of mass of some detected object. Transform that point into `camera`'s frame using a tf.TransformListener.
4. Project that point onto `camera`'s image plane using your camera model's `project3dToPixel`.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0